# Get a colon missing error after a else, but the colon is there

Tags: python

I'm using pycharm as IDE.

I'm getting a error that says there is a missing colon on a else staement.  But thee is a colon

code

```
def Start():
    glo.setUp();
    stat=1

    while state>0:
        if state==glo.STATE_PRE_START_BUY:
            sys.start()

            sys.end()
```

The error is on the line below

```
    else state==glo.STATE_BUY_CYCLE:  
        sys,end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> else state==glo.STATE_BUY_CYCLE:

I guess you meant

```
elif state==glo.STATE_BUY_CYCLE:
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an expression `state==glo.STATE_BUY_CYCLE` after `else`, which indicates that you really mean `elif` there. With `else` it needs to be immediately followed by a colon and not an expression.